# nginx with try_files and gzip_static serves only uncompressed

Tags: nginx

Wearing my system administrator hat, one of my app developers handed me this problem:

In his app directory, he has javascript files in app/assets/javascripts and app/public/javascripts.  In the public/javascripts directory there are both uncompressed and .gz files. The expectation is that nginx will server the compressed version of the javascripts.

In the nginx config file for the app, I've added this:

```
  location /javascripts {
    gzip on;
    gzip_static on;
    try_files /srv/app_dir/current/public/$uri /srv/app_dir/current/assets/$uri;
  }
```

With these parameters, the app works fine. All the .js files are found and served. But nginx never finds and serves the gzip version of the files.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting this?

Comment: My nginx build: nginx -V: nginx version: nginx/0.8.54
built by gcc 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/opt/nginx-0.8.54 --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --add-module=/var/chef/cache/headers-more-nginx-module --add-module=/var/chef/cache/chunkin-nginx-module

Answer (score 0):

Uncompressed files are not required on Nginx 1.6 with:

```
    location ~ \.txt$ {
        gzip_static on;
        gunzip on;
    }
```

Both `curl http://localhost/index.txt` and `curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://localhost/index.txt | gunzip` now work find with just `/srv/www/localhost/index.txt.gz` in my root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the answer from @hendry on nginx/1.13.8 and it doesn't work. It started working when I use "gzip_static always;" instead of "gzip_static on;".

```
location /fd/ {
    gunzip on;
    gzip_static always;
}
```

cURL output:

```
$ curl --silent -H "Accept-encoding: gzip" "http://myhost.com/fd/test.txt" | file -
/dev/stdin: gzip compressed data, from Unix
$ curl --silent "http://myhost.com/fd/test.txt" | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII text
```

Comment: Does not work with `try_files`. You need to keep original files https://serverfault.com/questions/571733/nginx-gzip-static-why-are-the-non-compressed-files-required/965094#965094